# Azure alerts action group: Not sending to webhook?

Tags: azure, microsoft-teams, alerts

I have an Azure alerts action group set up which sends an email to myself and 5 colleagues. No problem at all, we all receive the email.

In the same action group I have created another action this time as a Webhook instead of Email/SMS. The webhook URL that I am providing is for a Microsoft Team's channel which has the "Incoming Webhook" connector configured.

When alerts fire and the action group is alerted, the webhook does not appear to be working. Unfortunately, given the restraints of Azure, I cannot actually see any errors or attempts when sending to the webhook.

Anybody else encountered this issue?

Comment: Please take a look at [Webhook actions for log alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-log-webhook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone else had an issue around this a few weeks ago, perhaps your issue is the same - please check [Azure Monitor Alerts using webhook to Microsoft Teams - No messages to Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59883257/azure-monitor-alerts-using-webhook-to-microsoft-teams-no-messages-to-teams/59883941#59883941)